# How to create register form that depends on fields checking in mvc4?

Tags: javascript, ajax, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to create a register form in mvc 4 application. So, when user registers, in that time I want to define user's status (he is programmer or not) and to show (or hide) dynamically some extra fields to fill depending on user's choice.

In default case, all fields seems, if user is not programmer (by unchecking checkbox field), to hide **Language, Site and Probation** fields. My register model is like this:

```
public class RegisterModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "*", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "*")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Profession")]
        public bool IsProgrammer { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Language")]
        public string Language { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Site")]
        public string Site { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Probation")]
        public string Probation { get; set; }            
    }
```

If user is programmer, Language, Site and Probation fields are required, user must fill them.

How should I create Register model that, if user is not programmer, Language, Site and Probation fields **not required and let to register** ?

My second question is that, how show (hide) fields dynamically, when checkbox is checked (unchecked)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick search on 'mvc asp.net conditional required field' gave me these few links:

[Conditional Data Annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417113/asp-net-mvc-conditional-validation)

[Using IValidatableObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453560/conditional-data-annotation)

[Flexible Conditional Data Annotation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2011/10/06/flexible-conditional-validation-with-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx)

These are more targeted towards server-side validation.

So to answer your questions:

1. Check out the links, they will be helpful
2. You can use jQuery to achieve that, learn more about jQuery [Hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [Show](http://api.jquery.com/show/)